# Printing all values in a range on the same line

Tags: python

I want to get access to all the values inside a range() to have them all appear on the same line in the output.

This is for a program that will return all of the divisors of a whole number which is entered by the user.

```py
number = input("Enter a whole number: ")
list1 = range(1, (int(number)+1))
for element in list1:
    if int(number) % int(element) == 0:
       print("The divisors of " + str(number) + " are " + str(element))
```

And I want the last output to be:
`The divisors of number are x, y, z, ...`
But it is shown in the console with my codes:

```
The divisors of number are x
The divisors of number are y
The divisors of number are z
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using python2

```py
number = input("Enter a whole number: ")
list1 = range(1, (int(number)+1))

print "The divisors of " + str(number) + " are ", #Note the coma
for element in list1:
    if int(number) % int(element) == 0:
       print str(element) + ", ", #Note the coma
```

Or python3

```py
number = input("Enter a whole number: ")
list1 = range(1, (int(number)+1))

print("The divisors of " + str(number) + " are:", end=" ")
for element in list1:
    if int(number) % int(element) == 0:
       print(str(element) + ",", end=" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the place of print statement first and then print values:

```
#These are the existing codes:

number = input("Enter a whole number: ")
list1 = range(1, (int(number)+1))

print("The divisors of " + str(number) + " are : " ,end =" " ),

for element in list1:
    if int(number) % int(element) == 0:
       print( str(element) , end =" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code:

```
number = input("Enter a whole number: ")
list1 = range(1, (int(number)+1))
element_list = []
for element in list1:
    if int(number) % int(element) == 0:
        element_list.append(str(element))

print("The divisors of " + str(number) + " are " + ','.join(element_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to divide your output into two parts. You can try:

```py
#These are the existing codes:
number = input("Enter a whole number: ")
print("The divisors of " + str(number) + " are ", end='')
list1 = range(1, (int(number)+1))
for element in list1:
    if int(number) % int(element) == 0:
       print(str(element), end='')
```